# Error msg="append failed" err="expected equal, got \"INVALID\""

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-java

When I try to get the graph for a custom metrics I instrumented using Prometheus I got the error
"msg="append failed" err="expected equal, got \"INVALID\"".
Why this occurs and how to solve this?

Comment: Can you please post your application config/code and your prometheus server config?

Comment: Today I was able to figure the root cause for the issue. This has occurred due to a parsing error I have done while converting the metrics into Text format after extracting them from the Prometheus Default registry.

Comment: @N.Chandimali please put your solution here so others can use it.